# How to make apache solr URL POST Supported

Tags: solr, nutch

I am trying to integrate apache nucth and Solr and when nutch tries to dump the output to solr , it throws

```
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

I checked configurations but couldn't find the right point to make solr url POST supported , and I don't like to use Tomcat to drive solr , so how to make solr url POST supported

Comment: Solr supports POSTs by default. There is nothing you should need to configure. Are you pointing Nutch to the correct URL?

Comment: yeah.. I launched solr independently then it works but when I assign to nutch command , it fails , 1 thing to mention, I was trying the scenario in windows environment , not sure is that gonna change anything ... logically not ..but it windows...

Comment: Well, you'll need to add the nutch configuration at least, and some information about how you're running Solr - does /select?q=*:* on the URL give results? Are you able to add documents through /update in other ways?